# Gridview rows blinking

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I tried blink the rows of ASp:Gridview. Have succeded in IE but not working in FF and safari. FF error console says "Error: gridRef.childNodes is not a function" Can anybody tell me where exactly I am wrong...

The Javascript used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function blinkElement(elementId)
    {
        var elementRef = document.getElementById(elementId);
        var blinkCounter = parseInt(elementRef.blinkCounter);
        if ( isNaN(blinkCounter) == true )
            blinkCounter = 0;

        if ( (blinkCounter % 2) == 0 )
        {
            elementRef.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else
        {
            elementRef.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

        if ( blinkCounter < 1 )
        {
            blinkCounter++;
        } 
        else
        {
            blinkCounter--
        }

        elementRef.blinkCounter = blinkCounter;
        window.setTimeout('blinkElement(\"' + elementId + '\")', 700);
    }

    function blinkGridViewRows()
    {
        var gridRef = document.getElementById('<%= gvUsers.ClientID %>');

        for (var i=0; i<gridRef.childNodes.length; i++) 
        { 
            var bodyRef = gridRef.childNodes(i); 
            for (var j=0; j<bodyRef.childNodes.length; j++) 
            { 
                var trRef = bodyRef.childNodes(j);

                if ( trRef.blinkingRow == 'Y' )
                {
                    blinkElement(trRef.id);
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    window.onload = blinkGridViewRows;

    // -->
</script>
```

and on my gridview_rowdatabound I have

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("blinkingRow", "Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access items of an array in JavaScript with square brackets.
change

```
gridRef.childNodes(i);
```

to

```
gridRef.childNodes[i];
```

and

```
bodyRef.childNodes(j);
```

to

```
bodyRef.childNodes[j];
```

Regards,
Tim